# Android ndk-build command issue

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk

I have gone through this NDK example [link](http://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial).And i did all.But **ndk-build** not working(command not found).I tried ./ndk-build also but no success.I set the path variable too.I am using Ubuntu OS.Any help.Ndk path in bash.bashrc file is like this:

```
export NDK_HOME=/home/android/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86/android-ndk-r8e/
```

The big problem is i am doing cd to this folder in command prompt and doing **ndk-build** and it's not working.The file inside this filder is ndk-build.cmd

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: is ndk-build in the PATH ?

Comment: @mbrenon edited the question a little.it means command not found.it is not recognizing the command.

Comment: @blackbelt yes it is.Edited the question.

Comment: what gives you `ls $NDK_HOME`?

Comment: then is your user named "android"

Comment: @blackbelt yes.the user name is "android" only.

Comment: @gipi if i am doing in terminal without being inside any directory then it is giving me all folders inside "home" directory.

Comment: if you run source ~/.bashrc makes any difference?

Comment: @AndroidKiller it doesn't make sense, try `echo $NDK_HOME` and check if is the value is equal to what you have written in the question.

Comment: after edit `.bashrc` do you have opened another shell? otherwise the settings isn't loaded.

Comment: @gipi yes did that. no success.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run `ndk-build` this way, you need the path of the executable file to be in the `PATH` env variable. Otherwise you have to specify the entire path to `ndk-build`. For instace `/home/username/ndkpath/ndk-build`

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have get wrong the path, instead use

```
export NDK_HOME=/home/android/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86/
```

Comment: echo $NDK_HOME nothing is getting printed. :(

Comment: try to do `export NDK_HOME=...` in the shell and then run `ndk_build`

Comment: btw, ``ls /home/android/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86/android-ndk-r8e/`` what outputs?

Comment: i told u na there is another folder inside it.So the out put is that folder name i.e. android-ndk-r8e.

Comment: sorry, I edited the comment and in the between you answered :).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28725/discussion-between-android-killer-and-gipi)

Comment: it is printing all files inside that folder.

Comment: add  line EXPORT PATH=$PATH:NDK_HOME